# TURN servers: always or never needed for a given network, or needed unpredictably?

Tags: webrtc, nat, stun, turn

I am currently just using a STUN server and am wondering whether TURN is necessary for an MVP. The number of users accessing the website from a workplace with super secure firewalls should be near-zero.

Let's say 4 people are testing WebRTC connection reliability. Sometimes they all successfully connect and can see/hear one another, but other times they cannot see/hear someone and refresh the page to try again.

**Does the fact that they can sometimes all see/hear each other rule out whether a TURN server would make a difference?**

In other words, is it possible for a STUN server to identify my IP so I can connect one second, but fail if I try again a few seconds later?  Or is it just network-based, so if I a STUN doesn't work for me on my network now, it 100% will not work in 5 minutes either?

If the latter (and a TURN is either always or never needed for a given network), I guess that tells me the problem in my code is elsewhere...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NAT Traversal - Probability of success using STUN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23655243/nat-traversal-probability-of-success-using-stun)

Comment: The answer I gave 6 years ago is largely the same. But biggest change since then is the increased prevalence of IPv6, which might reduce the probability of symmetric NAT environment.

Comment: It comes very close to answering my question, but not quite. I'm just wondering:

if Kim connects to James via STUN on Try #1, and then they both refresh the page ~20 seconds later (with all environment factors, such as network connections, unchanged), are they guaranteed to connect via STUN again on Try #2?  Or is there a chance TURN will be used that time?

Comment: In theory, it should work the same.  There's always the possibility of a timing issue in the candidate selection algorithm or some other "cosmic ray" factor.